# "Then a message that . . ." with no main verb

Tags: grammar, conversational-deletion

In the following boldfaced sentence, a main verb is missing. Is this natural in native speech?

> “People got me out of my room at 3am. This night was a horror, I slept in my clothes in my bed because I was afraid that at any moment someone would take me back to isolation,” Maliszewska said. “**Then a message that unfortunately they were mistaken, that I am a threat, and should not have been released from isolation."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such sentences might be used to lend a sense of drama or urgency.

> A footstep on the stairs!
>
> Someone at the door, and from the silhouette I guessed it to be a man
> wearing a sombrero.

Or - as in your example perhaps - the speaker is simply abbreviating a wearisome or repetitive account of what happened.

> No beer, so I would have to get dressed, find my keys, get in the car
> and drive to a late-night off-licence.
>
> Then a phone call telling me to leave the house, taking nothing with me,
> and to walk to the High Street where I would be met an acrobat in Lycra riding an alpaca.

Comment: I think your examples are short and sweet, but the OP sentence is rather lengthy. Is the abbreviated style really suitable in the OP context?

Comment: @Apollyon: I lengthened some of  them.